# vb.net reading text file ,split to random range

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to read List's text line into a random range from 2 to 5 line and save to link.

For example: I have `test.txt` file which it contains the following:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
gg
hh
ii
yy
tt
rr
ee
ww
qq
uu
oo
pp
```

And this code:

```
Dim random As New Random()
Dim n As Integer
n = random.Next(2, 5)
Dim textfile As String = "test.txt"
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(textfile)
Dim List As String = objReader.ReadToEnd()
Do While Not EOF()
Dim link As List(Of String) = TextLink(resp)
Loop
```

So if I run it will read aa, bb and save to 'link' list of string and **continuously** it will read the next line like cc, dd, ee, ff randomly and save to 'link'.

This is what I want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Do you want the range to be in order (ex: aa,bb,cc,dd) or any random 3 lines from the text file?

Comment: hi..i want the range to be in orderly. thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
    Dim R As New Random
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim RangeLength As Integer
    Dim DataFileName As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "test.txt")
    Dim Links As New List(Of List(Of String))
    Using SR As New System.IO.StreamReader(DataFileName)
        While Not SR.EndOfStream
            Count = 0
            RangeLength = R.Next(2, 6)
            Dim curLinkSet As New List(Of String)
            Links.Add(curLinkSet)
            While Not SR.EndOfStream AndAlso Count < RangeLength
                curLinkSet.Add(SR.ReadLine)
                Count = Count + 1
            End While
        End While
    End Using

    For i As Integer = 0 To Links.Count - 1
        Debug.Print("Set #" & i)
        Dim LinkSet As List(Of String) = Links(i)
        For x As Integer = 0 To LinkSet.Count - 1
            Debug.Print(x & ": " & LinkSet(x))
        Next
        Debug.Print("")
    Next
```

Sample output:

```
Set #0
0: aa
1: bb
2: cc

Set #1
0: dd
1: ee
2: ff
3: gg
4: hh

Set #2
0: ii
1: yy
2: tt
3: rr

Set #3
0: ee
1: ww
2: qq
3: uu

Set #4
0: oo
1: pp
```

Comment: i tested it , it almost what i want but it read random line. i want to read line ordered way. so first time i want it read aa bb cc and second times it read dd ee and third it read ff gg hh and so on. this ordered way is what i want. thanks!

Comment: Ah...so you want to read the **entire** file in order, but "receive" it in random chunks of 2 to 5 lines at a time?

Comment: that's right. that is exactly what i implement! thanks

Comment: i really appreciate your help! this is exactly what i want to implement. thanks again!